# Python - Pandas group rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to summarize one table with Pandas, in another words I need to sum up values if two rows have the same word on one column

So I have a table like:

[image: Initial table]

And I want to sum the amounts if any of the columns "Name", "Product ID", "State" and "Type" have the same value, like this:

[image: Summarized]

On this case, just 'Ashley' got two amounts summed because she bought the same product, at the same state and the product belongs to the same type, all the other had one difference in any of the three columns

Paying attention to Jeff, if he had bought his food both in California or Texas, his amount would be summed too

Is it possible to do that with pandas?

I've tried doing something like df.groupby(['column']).sum() or level = 0 instead of column but it erases the others columns and don't do the differentiation between content

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please avoid using images in the question, it is not very helpful. It would be eaiser for other to help you if your issue could be reproduced easily. Instead of image try adding the data as text or code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! How would I represent this table as a text?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you use group by to sum a value based on groups, it means that every other column either stays the same and you can include them in the group by, or they differ and you have no other way than discarding them.
In your sample data for example either the phone number for each person stays the same, or you have to consider them different people. So if any of the other columns should remain the same you can add them to the group by and it won't affect the summation:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Phone', 'Product ID', 'State', 'Type'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

If in a specific scenario you have some changes that you want to keep and assign the same sum to them, for example, each person may be present with a second phone number and you want to have two rows with both numbers and the same sum, then you will have to create a dataframe with all the 'Name' and 'Phone' number combinations, and then merge the groupby result.